# R: extracting values from summary object and turning it into a list

Tags: r

I am running the command `summary()` on a dataset in the following way:

```
d = summary(dataset)
```

and printing `d` gives me this result:

```
7/4/2015   8/27/2015   7/4/2012   8/29/2015   7/5/2015   8/7/2015
     754         738        736        725         733       345
```

I'd like to remove the incidents of dates and obtain the counts (754, 738, 736, 725, 733, 345) in a list. I've tried looking at other questions and sites, but I can't seem to find a general helpful answer.

Thanks

Comment: How about `as.vector(d)` or `unname(d)` assuming that you have a named vector as output.  If you need it as list, wrap with `as.list` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that 'dataset' object is a `vector` with `class` as `factor`, the output of `summary` will be a named vector.  We can remove the `names` attribute by using `as.vector` or with `unname`

```
as.vector(d)
```

Or

```
unname(d)
```